# ¡Empieza el Winter Bash 2017! / Let the Winter Bash 2017 start!

Tags: discusión, winter-bash

¿Habéis visto un nuevo icono copo de nieve en la parte superior de la barra de usuario? ¡Se trata del [Winter Bash 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/?cb=1)!

Tenemos desde hoy, 13 de diciembre de 2017, hasta el 2 de enero de 2018 para conseguir estos sombreros (después de lo cual desaparecerán todos). Los sombreros, para quienes no lo sepan, son algo así como las medallas, pero mejores porque los puedes "vestir" en tu avatar, mostrándolos donde quiera que tu avatar aparezca, ¡en toda la red! Eso sí, no son permanentes. Al terminar el Winter Bash los sombreros desaparecen. ¡Disfrutadlos mientras podáis!

Para saber cómo conseguir los sombreros, visitad este enlace a [una lista de sombreros del Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/). Existen ciertos sombreros "secretos" y no se explica en esa lista cómo conseguirlos. ¡Hay que investigar y participar!

Postead una respuesta si tenéis dudas o problemas con esa funcionalidad, o si simplemente queréis mostrar una captura de pantalla de vuestro avatar vistiendo alguno de estos sombreros.

¡**Participad** y pasadlo bien!

Answer (score 2):

@charlie, puestos a fardar, enhorabuena por

[image]

Este es un sombrero secreto, pero viendo ese "rep" entiendo que tiene algo que ver con esa recompensa de 300 reps (creo que la mayor que hemos visto en el sitio, cortesía de [James Bolivar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18111/james-bolivar)) por "[¿De dónde viene la expresión “indirecta del padre Cobos”, que es una verdad desnuda y no una “indirecta”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23444/5481)".

Gracias a James Bolivar por "investor" y "benefactor" (aunque no son las primeras recompensas que ofrece ni otorga) y a Charlie por sus increíbles esfuerzos de investigación.

---

Personalmente, creo que te quedaba mejor

[image]

:-P

Comment: ¡No había visto este post! La verdad es que sí, las gafas me quedaban bien, y sí, el gorro "rep" fue por la recompensa de 300 puntos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo hasta me cambié de avatar para poder usar sombrero con dignidad en una cabeza como dios manda. Cambio de sombrero continuamente, ahora estoy usando este:

[image]

Comment: Me encantaba cuando llevabas el "This Is Fine". Ese sombrero es hilarante.

Answer (score 1):

Pues nada, vamos a empezar a fardar de sombrero.

[image: Sherlock]

Este sombrero (llamado *Sherlock*) se consigue cuando autorrespondes tu propia pregunta, y tanto la pregunta como la respuesta consiguen 3 votos positivos. Así que muchas gracias a todos los que votaron en *[¿Se escribe "r" simple para el sonido "rr" tras otras consonantes aparte de "l", "n" y "s"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23562/12637)*

---

¿Y qué tal una buena pizza? Justo hoy me acabo de zampar una...

[image]

Este te lo dan por escribir una respuesta de +3 a una pregunta que ya tenía una respuesta aceptada. Así que gracias a todos los que me han votado en *[Is "paparrucha" a good translation of "fake news" and "post-truth"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22617/12637)*.

Answer (score 1):

Va, fardo yo también de sombreros secretos :D

[image][image][image][image][image]

- **Cosmic Brain**: por obtener el [badge de Nice Answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) durante el evento.
- **Some Kind Of Sun Thingy**: por participar en cualquier stack durante el Solsticio de Invierno (21 de diciembre).
- **Row of Many Candles**: por participar en cualquier stack el último día de Hannukah (19 de diciembre).
- **Red Hat With White Fur Trim**: por participar en cualquier stack el día de Navidad (25 de diciembre).
- **Ooh, Shiny!**: por ponerle un flag de cierre a una pregunta, o votar para el cierre, borrado o reapertura de una pregunta.

Al principio creía que el de las velas lo daban por votar positivamente una pregunta junto con todas sus respuestas. La verdad es que, en mi mente, el símil de votar/"encender" todas las respuestas/"velas" "in a row" (de seguido), tenía bastante sentido, pero ¡en fin! :D

Así ha quedado mi colección completa, la explicación del resto de gorros está en https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com:

[image]

Comment: A mi me han dado el de las velas en cuatro stacks en 3 días distintos, algo no cuadra.

Answer (score 0):

Demos la enhorabuena al ganador walen, que *copa* la [clasificación](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/spanish.stackexchange.com) con su arsenal de... sombreros de copa ;-)

[image]

Comment: @walen efectivamente. En la imagen se ve que yo era el que _lo_ tenía más grande ;-D