# ¡Empieza el Winter Bash 2018! / Let the Winter Bash 2018 start!

Tags: discusión, promoción-de-la-comunidad, winter-bash

¿Habéis visto un nuevo icono copo de nieve en la parte superior de la barra de usuario? ¡Se trata del [Winter Bash 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/)!

Yo me acabo de dar cuenta de que estaba. ¿Me he perdido alguna notificación?

Tenemos desde hoy, 12 de diciembre de 2018, hasta el 1 de enero de 2019 para conseguir estos sombreros (después de lo cual desaparecerán todos). Los sombreros, para quienes no lo sepan, son algo así como las medallas, pero mejores porque los puedes "vestir" en tu avatar, mostrándolos donde quiera que tu avatar aparezca, ¡en toda la red! Eso sí, no son permanentes. Al terminar el Winter Bash los sombreros desaparecen. ¡Disfrutadlos mientras podáis! ¡Fardad de ellos!

Para saber cómo conseguir los sombreros, visitad este enlace a [una lista de sombreros del Winter Bash 2018](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/). Existen ciertos sombreros "secretos" y no se explica en esa lista cómo conseguirlos. ¡Hay que investigar y participar!

Postead una respuesta si tenéis dudas o problemas con esa funcionalidad, o si simplemente queréis mostrar una captura de pantalla de vuestro avatar vistiendo alguno de estos sombreros [como ya hicimos el año pasado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2752/5481).

¡**Participad** y pasadlo bien!

Comment: Diego, estamos esperando a que fardes de sombrero "Rubber Ducky", que de momento nadie sabe cómo se consigue. :-)

Comment: Quizá por preguntar en Meta, porque es de lo poco que he hecho (aparte de atender las colas de revisión y flags) en el día de ayer. Voy a ponerme a preguntar, responder y votar como loco!!!

Comment: Parece que el sombrero "Rubber Ducky" ya han descubierto cómo se consigue: "Use the discard button on any 'Ask A Question' page." Se ve que fuiste a preguntar algo y te arrepentiste... :-D

Comment: @Charlie Me pasa con frecuencia. A menudo me vienen ideas para preguntar en el stack, pero si no las apunto lo más seguro es que no las recuerde luego. Una vez apuntadas, tengo que sacar tiempo (y ganas) para redactar la pregunta. Y a veces mientras escribo la pregunta y la documento un poco me viene a la cabeza la posible respuesta. Eso me pasó el otro día, pero ya ni me acuerdo qué es lo que estaba preguntado... ;-D

Answer (score 1):

Venga, empiezo yo, que las gafas rojas me sientan muy bien...

[image: Gafas rojas]

Estas gafas son un "gorro secreto", se consiguen al parecer votando una pregunta o respuesta que se haya publicado hace más de un año. En mi caso voté la pregunta  [Tener gracia (funny) vs. Tener gracia (graceful)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12595/12637), y de paso podéis echar un vistazo a [la respuesta que he publicado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28037/12637) (toma promoción)... :-)

Menos secreto es el gorro "Member of the Hand", que se consigue escribiendo un post como novato y obteniendo una puntuación de al menos +3, que me han otorgado gracias a [mi primera pregunta](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/50186/35870) en History (derivada de una pregunta de este sitio):

[image: Order of the hand]

Comment: reconoce que estás probando si hay un sombrero por promocionar una respuesta tuya :P

Comment: @fedorqui pues no era mi intención, pero mira, ya te puedo decir que no lo hay. :-D

Answer (score 0):

El más *raruno* que yo tengo hasta la fecha es el casco de Robocop.

[image: mis sombreros]

otorgado por <strike>ser un robot sin alma</strike>

> successfully complete 20 reviews without failing an audit

*Update*

[image]

- Propel Thyself
- Clean-up Duty